# $8$ children played. $4$ games of $G1, 3$ of $G2, 10$ of $G3$ Winner gets gift. Three types of gifts. Find Number of ways for getting gifts.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Problem Statement**
$8$ children came to the court and played

- $4$ games of $\text{Game-1}$
- $3$ games of $\text{Game-2}$
- $10$ games of $\text{Game-3}$

Winner of each game gets gift. There are different gift to all games (Three types of gifts). How many options are there for getting gifts?

None of the children won more than $4$ games of $\text{Game-3}$.

**My Attempt :** I thought of taking all the possibilities and subtracting the possibility that someone would win $5,6,7,8,9,10$ but it seems too complicated.

Comment: Please clarify.  Do all winners of the same game win the same type of gift?  In that case, we have four gifts of type 1, three gifts of type 2, and ten gifts of type 3 to distribute to eight children.  Please edit your question to clarify this point.   When you edit the question, you should also show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  Do you know how to solve the problem without the restriction that no child wins more than four games of game 3?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.  Without the restriction that no child wins game 3 more than four times, the distribution of prizes for each game is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.  Please edit your question to show your attempt.